# Any explicity form for such function?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request

$f(x)$is a analytic function in a circle,$f^{[j]}(0)=j! c,c \in [0,1,\dots,m],m<M$,$M$ is a constant.

Is there explicity form or partial explicity form for $f(x)$?

Comment: Is $c$ a constant, or can it vary for different $j$?

Comment: @martycohen  it varies for different $j$

Comment: Just write down the Taylor expansion of the function, then you have your explicit form.

Comment: @luke I try to find another form like closed form

Comment: If $c$ can vary with $j$, there are uncountably many possibilities for $f$, but only countably many possible "explicit forms", if an explicit form corresponds to a string of finite length in a fixed alphabet.